Tween fantasy book where a boy and his friend discover magic exists and they have magic
This is a series I read 15 yrs ago and all I can really remember is a boy discovers magic, his friend is maybe named Violet. One of the book covers is two kids running up invisible stairs up towards the sky on a cloudy day over a cityscape below them. I believe at one point Violet falls ill/is cursed and can only be saved by her true love's voice who turns out to be this immortal person who was also their mentor and had blue hair??

The last sentence sounds a little like Marianne Curley's Guardians of Time series; the girl is named Isabel in that, but she is saved by and discovers she is soulmates with (blue-haired) Arkarian, the ageless son of the immortal Lorian. Her friend is named Ethan. Other aspects don't really match, though.
